# Maintain a straight edge when applying texture

Tags: inkscape, texture

I have an object to which I apply Filters > Textures > Rough Paper
The object has straight edges and when I apply the filter they become irregular. I would like to get the texture but keep the edges straight.
How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the object, and then go to *Filters -> Filter editor*.

Click on *Displacement map* (this is the component that randomly displaces the shape (and its border).

Select a scale of 0.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks!